# PascalABC, обучение

Tags: pascal

Даны электронные часы, и нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь мог забить время самостоятельно, на часах есть 7 подсвеченных индикаторов.
не знаю, где ошибка. При запуске

> Program1.pas(37) : Встречено 'procedure', а ожидался оператор

```
program TIME;
var a,b,c,d,e,f,g:boolean;
procedure zero;
begin 
writeln(' a'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('f| |b'); 
writeln(' g'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('e| |c'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln(' d'); 
writeln('Индикатор a? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
readln(a); 
writeln('Индикатор f? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
readln(f); 
writeln('Индикатор b? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
readln(b); 
writeln('Индикатор g? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
readln(g); 
writeln('Индикатор e? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
readln(e); 
writeln('Индикатор c? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
readln(c); 
writeln('Индикатор d? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
readln(d);
begin 
if ((a=1) and (f=1) and (b=1) and (g=0) and (e=1) and (c=1) and (d=1)) then 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('| |'); 
writeln('| |'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('Цифра 0');
end;


procedure one;
begin 
if ((a=0) and (f=0) and (b=1) and (g=0) and (e=0) and (c=1) and (d=0)) then 
writeln(' |'); 
writeln(' |'); 
writeln('Цифра 1'); 
end;

procedure two;
begin
if ((a=1) and (f=0) and (b=1) and (g=1) and (e=1) and (c=0) and (d=1)) then 
writeln('__'); 
writeln(' |'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('| '); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('Цифра 2');
end;

procedure three;
begin
if ((a=1) and (f=0) and (b=1) and (g=0) and (e=0) and (c=1) and (d=1)) then 
writeln('__'); 
writeln(' |'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln(' |'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('Цифра 3'); 
end;
procedure four;
begin
if ((a=0) and (f=1) and (b=1) and (g=1) and (e=0) and (c=1) and (d=0)) then 
writeln('| |'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln(' |'); 
writeln('Цифра 4'); 
end;

procedure five;
begin 
if ((a=1) and (f=1) and (b=0) and (g=1) and (e=0) and (c=1) and (d=1)) then 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('| '); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln(' |'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('Цифра 5'); 
end;

procedure six;
begin
if ((a=1) and (f=1) and (b=0) and (g=1) and (e=1) and (c=1) and (d=1)) then 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('| '); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('| |'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('Цифра 6'); 
end;

procedure seven;
begin
if ((a=1) and (f=0) and (b=1) and (g=0) and (e=0) and (c=1) and (d=0)) then 
writeln('__'); 
writeln(' |'); 
writeln(' |'); 
writeln('Цифра 7');
end;

procedure eight;
begin 
if ((a=1) and (f=1) and (b=1) and (g=1) and (e=1) and (c=1) and (d=1)) then 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('| |'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('| |'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('Цифра 8'); 
end;

procedure nine;
begin
if ((a=1) and (f=1) and (b=1) and (g=1) and (e=0) and (c=1) and (d=1)) then 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('| |'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln(' |'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('Цифра 9');

end;
end.
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35118/discussion-on-question-by-marble-pascalabc-).

Answer (score 2):

Основная ошибка в том, что определены процедуры, но не определено тело основной программы, а именно нет конструкции

```
begin
end.
```

Судя по всему в ней должен был осуществляться ввод параметров, следовательно этот код как раз и должен был быть основной программой

```
begin 
    writeln(' a'); 
    writeln('__'); 
    writeln('f| |b'); 
    writeln(' g'); 
    writeln('__'); 
    writeln('e| |c'); 
    writeln('__'); 
    writeln(' d'); 
    writeln('Индикатор a? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
    readln(a); 
    writeln('Индикатор f? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
    readln(f); 
    writeln('Индикатор b? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
    readln(b); 
    writeln('Индикатор g? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
    readln(g); 
    writeln('Индикатор e? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
    readln(e); 
    writeln('Индикатор c? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
    readln(c); 
    writeln('Индикатор d? Да - 1, нет - 0.'); 
    readln(d);
```

Далее, нет ни одного вызова описанных процедур, следовательно после ввода программа просто завершится и ничего не выведет.

Для решения, нужно добавить вызовы этих процедур в основную программу.

---

Следующая ошибка:

```
if ((a=1) and (f=0) and (b=1) and (g=0) and (e=0) and (c=1) and (d=0))
```

В условиях идет попытка сравнения булевской переменной и целого числа, но при этом вы получаете следующую ошибку

> Операция '=' не применима к типам boolean и integer

Чтобы избежать этого можно опустить сравнение, так как переменные и так имеют тип boolean, для проверки что переменная `true` - достаточно использовать саму переменную, а для проверки что она `false` - нужно использовать оператор `not`. Таким образом приведенное выше выражение приобретет вид

```
if (a and not f and b and not g and not e and c and not d)
```

Аналогично следует преобразовать оставшиеся условия.
Но при этом придется вводить не просто `1`, `0`, а именно `true`, `false`.
Вместо этого можно просто поменять тип переменных на Integer

---

Следующая ошибка:

конструкция `if...then` подразумевает что после `then` идет **единственное** выражение, таким образом для следующего кода

```
if ((a=1) and (f=1) and (b=1) and (g=1) and (e=0) and (c=1) and (d=1)) then 
    writeln('__'); 
writeln('| |'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln(' |'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('Цифра 9');
```

условие будет влиять **только** на первый `writeln`, остальные будут выполняться всегда.

Чтобы этого избежать необходимо использовать составной оператор `begin...end;` таким образом

```
if ((a=1) and (f=1) and (b=1) and (g=1) and (e=0) and (c=1) and (d=1)) then 
begin
    writeln('__'); 
    writeln('| |'); 
    writeln('__'); 
    writeln(' |'); 
    writeln('__'); 
    writeln('Цифра 9');
end;
```

Итоговый код может выглядеть так:

```
program TIME;
var a,b,c,d,e,f,g:boolean;
  procedure zero;
  begin 
    if (a and f and b and not g and e and c and d) then 
    begin
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('| |'); 
      writeln('| |'); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('Цифра 0');
    end;
  end;


  procedure one;
  begin 
    if (not a and not f and b and not g and not e and c and not d) then 
    begin
      writeln(' |'); 
      writeln(' |'); 
      writeln('Цифра 1'); 
    end;
  end;

  procedure two;
  begin
    if (a and not f and b and g and e and not c and d) then 
    begin
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln(' |'); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('| '); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('Цифра 2');
    end;
  end;

  procedure three;
  begin
    if ( a and not f and b and not g and not e and c and d) then 
    begin
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln(' |'); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln(' |'); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('Цифра 3'); 
    end;
  end;

  procedure four;
  begin
  if ( not a and f and b and g and not e and c and not d) then 
    begin
      writeln('| |'); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln(' |'); 
      writeln('Цифра 4'); 
    end;
  end;

  procedure five;
  begin 
    if (a and f and not b and g and not e and c and d) then 
    begin
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('| '); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln(' |'); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('Цифра 5'); 
    end;
  end;

  procedure six;
  begin
    if (a and f and not b and g and e and c and d) then 
    begin
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('| '); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('| |'); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('Цифра 6'); 
    end;
  end;

  procedure seven;
  begin
    if (a and not f and b and not g and not e and c and not d) then 
    begin
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln(' |'); 
      writeln(' |'); 
      writeln('Цифра 7');
    end;
  end;

  procedure eight;
  begin 
    if (a and f and b and g and e and c and d) then 
    begin
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('| |'); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('| |'); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('Цифра 8'); 
    end;
  end;

  procedure nine;
  begin
    if (a and f and b and g and not e and c and d) then 
    begin
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('| |'); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln(' |'); 
      writeln('__'); 
      writeln('Цифра 9');
    end;
  end;

// Основная программа
begin 
writeln(' a'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('f| |b'); 
writeln(' g'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln('e| |c'); 
writeln('__'); 
writeln(' d'); 
writeln('Индикатор a? Да - true, нет - false.'); 
readln(a); 
writeln('Индикатор f? Да - true, нет - false.'); 
readln(f); 
writeln('Индикатор b? Да - true, нет - false.'); 
readln(b); 
writeln('Индикатор g? Да - true, нет - false.'); 
readln(g); 
writeln('Индикатор e? Да - true, нет - false.'); 
readln(e); 
writeln('Индикатор c? Да - true, нет - false.'); 
readln(c); 
writeln('Индикатор d? Да - true, нет - false.'); 
readln(d);
one;
two;
three;
four;
five;
six;
seven;
eight;
nine;
end.
```